# Hide parameters for flash (.swf)

Tags: php, flash, .htaccess

I have one flash file that accepts two arguments arg1 and arg2. I am trying to hide both of the arguments (or minimum arg1). I used following code to achieve this task:

```
<embed width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://www.****.com/url.php" allowscriptaccess="always" bgcolor="#ffffff"/>
```

url.php code is as follows:

```
<?php
$file = ‘example.swf’;

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Type: application/x-shockwave-flash');
    header('Content-Disposition: inline;filename=example.swf’);
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

It works all fine but it does not pass arg1 and arg2 to swf file. I can't pass arg1 and arg2 in readFile function. I tried and it doesn't work.

Is there any solution? Is there way I can pass these two arguments using .htaccess? I tried below code as well for .htaccess but no success:

```
RewriteRule ^example.swf$  example.swf?arg1=454&arg2=wed[L]
```

Summary:
Is there a way I can embed .swf file in my page without showing argument values in html/php files?

PS: I do not have access to .swf source file.

Comment: Sidenote: The curly quotes in `‘example.swf’` will cause you headaches/errors. Change to `'example.swf'` because it will "not work fine"; ***believe me***. And `header('Content-Disposition: inline;filename=example.swf’);` to `header('Content-Disposition: inline;filename=example.swf');` and who knows, might even be the/a cause.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't make any difference. Those quotes were due to copy past from an editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate encrypted arguments and use some obfuscated javascript code at client side to pass decrypted values to the swfobject embedding library. It isn't weaker protection than straight arguments in headers.

Comment: Is there any online tutorial or tool to encrypt arguments? I am using php+swf

Comment: You can simply XOR arguments with long key or have substitution cipher table. Anyway you can't make strong protection because you have to pass arguments to SWF in decrypted state.